# MooTools slide jumps around in wrapping div

Tags: css, mootools, mootools-fx

I'm using a slide effect for 'closing' a `div`, which works fine, except before sliding, it jumps diagonally in its wrapping `div`, next to a floating `div` that's above it. Making it look ugly...

This illustrates exactly what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/ELxPF/

When the floated `div` is not floated, all is well, so it has something to do with the float. I think the wrapper that is applied to the non-floating `div` when the slide effect is initiated, does not do `clear: both;` or something to that effect, causing it to leap diagonally.

What's the best way to resolve this, retaining the floatability of the floating `div` - and preferably without using extra wrapper elements?

Comment: was one of these demo what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry, took me some time to implement as I had to revise my MooTools code. That did not contain the necessary class for Reveal, and I had some custom bits thrown in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you  use **[.dissolve()](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Reveal#Element%3adissolve)** instead.

```
$('slide').addEvent('click', function () {
    $('two').dissolve()
});
```

### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DY9vr/)

And then you can use `.reveal()` to bring it back.

```
$('slide').addEvent('click', function () {
    $('two').dissolve();
});
$('one').addEvent('click', function () {
    $('two').reveal();
});
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. The slide-and-fade effect is even nicer than just sliding. Thanks for this solution, but do you perhaps know what causes the `div` to jump when sliding, as shown in my example? I'm guessing some floating issues, I'm not sure however.